# Histogram of Weekdays by Year R

Tags: r, csv, histogram

I have a .csv file that I have loaded into R using the following basic command:

`lace <- read.csv("lace for R.csv")`

It pulls in my data just fine. Here is the `str` of the data:

```
str(lace)
'data.frame':   2054 obs. of  20 variables:
 $ Admission.Day       : Factor w/ 872 levels "1/1/2013","1/10/2011",..: 231 238 238 50 59 64 64 64 67 67 ...
 $ Year                : int  2010 2010 2010 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 2011 ...
 $ Month               : int  12 12 12 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Day                 : int  28 30 30 3 4 6 6 6 7 7 ...
 $ DayOfWeekNumber     : int  3 5 5 2 3 5 5 5 6 6 ...
 $ Day.of.Week         : Factor w/ 7 levels "Friday","Monday",..: 6 5 5 2 6 5 5 5 1 1 ...
```

What I am trying to do is create three (3) different histograms and then plot them all together on one. I want to create a histogram for each year, where the x axis or labels will be the days of the week starting with Sunday and ending on Saturday.

Firstly how would I go about creating a histogram out of Factors, which the days of the week are in?

Secondly how do I create a histogram for the days of the week for a given year?

I have tried using the following post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923223/how-to-histogram-day-of-week-and-have-string-labels) but cannot get it working. I use the `Admission.Day` as the variable and get an error message:

`dat <- as.Date(lace$Admission.Day)`

`Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Thank you,

Comment: The first thing you need to do is read the documentation for `?as.Date`, in particular the description for the `format` argument. Next, you'll want to look at the function `?weekdays`.

Comment: `as.Date` needs an origin `dat <- as.Date(lace$Admission.Day, origin="1970-01-01")`

Comment: @joran got all the dates now, thank you for pointing out the format part, not having an origin as specified by excel was really throwing everything off.

Comment: weird I do the same thing three times over and one of the files does not work

Comment: also to get the dates that I want I am doing something like this:
`radf <- data.frame(lace[lace$FAILURE == 1,])`

Comment: @joran if you want to put that as your answer I'll mark it as accepted, I was able to take part of the second question

Comment: Sounds like your problem is with importing dates, rather than making histograms. If your data starts out in Excel, I'd strongly recommend you consider the `XLConnect` package, especially `loadWorkbook(...)` and `readWorksheet(...)`. In my experience, this package does a much better job interpreting Excel dates. See the documentation [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the comment above: the problem seems to be with importing dates, rather than making the histogram. Assuming there is an excel workbook "lace for R.xlsx", with a sheet "lace":

```
## Not tested...
library(XLConnect)
myData <- "lace for R.xlsx"             # NOTE: need path also...
wb     <- loadWorkbook(myData)
lace   <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet="lace")
lace$Admission.Day <- as.Date(lace$Admission.Day)
```

should provide dates that work with all the R date functions. Also, the [lubridate](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html) package provides a number of functions that are more intuitive to use than `format(...)`.

Then, as an example:

```
library(lubridate)   # for year(...) and wday(...)
library(ggplot2)
# random dates around Jun 1, across 5 years...
set.seed(123)
lace <- data.frame(date=as.Date(rnorm(1000,sd=50)+365*(0:4),origin="2008/6/1"))
lace$year <- factor(year(lace$date))
lace$dow  <- wday(lace$date, label=T)
# This creates the histograms...
ggplot(lace) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=dow, fill=year)) +      # fill color by year
  facet_grid(~year) +                          # facet by year
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))    # to rotate weekday names...
```

Produces this:
[image]

Comment: Anyone trying to get this to work might like to try ```geom_bar(aes(x=dow, fill=year))``` to replace ```geom_histogram(aes(x=dow, fill=year))```